# Callback this context

Tags: javascript, callback, this

in App:

```
var bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.init( this, this.onBootstrapComplete );
```

in Bootstrap:

```
this.init = function( app, completeHandler ){
    _app = app;
    _completeHandler = completeHandler;
        ...
}

...

var _allReady = function(){
        _completeHandler( _app );
}
```

back in App:

```
this.onBootstrapComplete = function( app )
{
        app.something();
        app.someValue = ...
}
```

I wanted to get **this** context inside onBootstrapComplete.
It works but it doesn't look right :)

If let's say I wanted to call onBootstrapComplete directly from App, I would have to call it **this**.onBootstrapComplete( **this** ).

How can I do it so my onBootstrapComplete looks like this:

```
this.onBootstrapComplete = function()
{
        this.something();
        this.someValue = ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want, but maybe [reading some documentation about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using underscore.js. See http://underscorejs.org/#bind for further information.

```
this.onBootstrapComplete = _.bind( function() {
   ...
   this.someFunction(); // this context is available now
   ... 
}, this );
```

Comment: I shorten it down to: bootstrap.init( this, _.bind( this.onBootstrapComplete, this ) );

Answer (score 1):

`this` is evaluated when the function is called. Say you use `this` inside a function `f`.

There are basically two ways to call `f`:

**`(expr).f()`** if f is called as a property on some object, `this` will evaluate to that object `expr`.
**`f()`** In this case, `this` will evaluate to `window`.

Since you pass the function to `bootstrap`, it can only call the function as `f()`.

You could use a closure:

```
var self = this;
this.onBootstrapComplete = function()
{
        self.something();
        self.someValue = ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a function to `f.apply()` the function appropriately:

```
function bind(context, f){
    return function() {
        return f.apply(context, arguments);
    }
}

this.onBootstrapComplete = bind(this, function()
{
        this.something();
        this.someValue = ...
});
```

Or with ECMAScript 5, there [**is already a bind function**<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
this.onBootstrapComplete = function()
{
        this.something();
        this.someValue = ...
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong with anything. I am trying to pick the best option. [3rd option] IE8 has 24% penetration, so may be to early for this. [1st option] Looks clean and less memory hungry then [2nd option]. BTW [1st option] isn't really a closure is it? :) By 'memory hungry' I actuly mean a risk of a js noobie(me) falling into lots of memory leaks

Comment: @user2015338 Yes, it is a closure: It closes over the `self` variable. AFAIK there are no memory leaks in these functions, unless `this` is a DOM object and you're using a browser that only employs reference counting, but I'm not really sure. You'd best ask a new question about just that issue to get a more authorative answer.

Comment: @user2015338: Basically every function is a closure in JavaScript. You cannot create functions that don't have access to a higher lexical scope.

Comment: Thank you phant0m, I was watching this video about closures at the same time http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRm-h6vcpxs @10min53sec he says: A closure is created when a function is returned from another function, retaining its original scope. This is the reason why I asked :)